# Get single column of values comparing multiple columns

Tags: r

I have just started my journey with R. I want to test values across multiple columns for the same condition and return 5 if any of the values is "hello" within a row:

```
result = ifelse((myData[1] == "hello") | (myData[2] == "hello") | (myData[3] == "hello"), 5, 0)
```

This works fine, but code seems to be redundant. When I do:

```
resultSec = ifelse(myData[1:3] == "hello", 5, 0)
```

Then all 3 columns are checked against the condition, but the result I get is not a single column, but 3 columns. So then I would have to perform an additional comparison for all columns which makes totally more lines of code then the first redundant method.
How can I get in this case a one column of values in efficient way ?

Comment: use `any` instead of ifelse

Comment: or `resultSec = ifelse(any(myData[1:3] == "hello"), 5, 0)`

Comment: Unfortunately both of them returned a single value and not a column of values for all rows. I want to get the exact same result as here:
    result = ifelse((myData[1] == "hello") | (myData[2] == "hello") | (myData[3] == "hello"), 5, 0)
but without testing explicitly each column for being equal to "hello"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `apply()` to iterate over a data.frame or matrix, by either columns or rows. The `margin` argument determines which one you use.

Here we want to check the rows, so we use `margin = 1`:

```
dat <- data.frame(col1 = c("happy", "sad", "mad"),
                  col2 = c("tired", "sleepy", "happy"),
                  col3 = c("relaxed", "focused", "fine"))

dat$res <- apply(X = dat, MARGIN = 1,
                FUN = function(x) ifelse("happy" %in% x, 5, 0))

dat

   col1   col2    col3 res
1 happy  tired relaxed   5
2   sad sleepy focused   0
3   mad  happy    fine   5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowSums` here

```
df1$res <-  rowSums(df1 == "happy") * 5
df1$res
#[1] 5 0 5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("happy", 
"mad", "sad"), class = "factor"), col2 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("happy", "sleepy", "tired"), class = "factor"), 
col3 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("fine", "focused", 
"relaxed"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("col1", "col2", 
"col3"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```